# Docker in Docker without priviledged mode?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to run docker daemon inside a docker container. But I need to run docker daemon in privilege mode. Only then I can run the daemon inside container. Is there any other way to run a docker daemon without privilege mode? Because privilege mode gives access to all the resources of the outside container and the machine on which that container is running. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Create a docker group, as described [here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) You do need to be superuser to add yourself.

Comment: Referencing documentation is not an answer

Comment: @nischaygoyal Are you suggesting that I cut and paste from that page? Obviously the OP did not know of the existence of the docker group, so his/her question was answered.

Comment: @IgorRivin I've already tried that out. The issue is that unless I give privilege access, I cannot run docker inside docker. And on giving privilege, the inner docker gets complete access of the system because it attaches the daemon to the external docker.

Comment: @gapc311,  I have noticed that many sites that mention loading the docker.sock as without --privileged the ability to keep the daemon running appears to be an issue. I am looking for a very similar solution, if I manage to find one then I will try share my findings